# Rasterlite db with multi table

Tags: qgis, raster, spatialite, rasterlite

When working with Spatialite DBs, I can store multiple tables in single DB. But now I want to store multiple raster tables on a single Rasterlite DB. I tried QGIS for conversion but it converts only one table not more... (I am using Windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS uses the [Geospatial Data Extraction Library](http://www.gdal.org/) (GDAL) for raster works. So you must work with GDAL library and its functions. From QGIS menus open the **Raster > Translate > Translation (Convert format)** tool. With this tool you can convert raster formats. Firstly look at the bottom of the windows. This area shows the conversion parameters. We need to change it by clicking pencil icon (red frame). And enter this command:

[image]

`gdal_translate -of rasterlite -a_srs epsg:3067 F:\temporary\Raster\sfdem2.tif rasterlite:F:\temporary\Raster\multiRasterlite.sqlite,table=sfdem2`

Change the path of files for yourself and click OK.

We can specify multi tables with the **table** option. In this example we named the table as **sfdem2**. Next time put another name as your table option. You can also run this tool from the command line.

Comment: Thx for fast answer.